# Change the projection at runtime (OpenLayers)

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

How do I change the projection on an existing Map object? I'd like to allow a user to switch between cylindrical (EPSG:4326) and custom-declared projections with the click of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out might be helpful for you http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olchangingprojection.html and http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/users/2011-June/002310.html

The GeoExt mailing list post, mentions the following:

> I've had similar problems and I've solved it by adding an event
>   listener to the map's baselayerchange event. you would put
>   mapOptionsEtrs properties on the Etrs base layer rather than on the
>   map. Map options are most ignored and overwritten by base layer
>   options.
>
> here is my baselayerchange event handler, which is called with the map
>   as scope.

```
function onBaseLayerChange(evtObj){
   var mapProj, baseProj, map, newBase, reproject;
   map = this;
   newBase = evtObj.layer;
   mapProj = (map.projection && map.projection instanceof OpenLayers.Projection) ? map.projection : new OpenLayers.Projection(map.projection);
   baseProj = newBase.projection;
   reproject = !(baseProj.equals(mapProj));
   if (reproject) {
      var center, maxExt;
      //calc proper reporojected center
      center = map.getCenter().transform(mapProj, baseProj);
      //calc correct reprojected extents
      maxExt = newBase.maxExtent;
      //set map projection, extent, & center of map to proper values
      map.projection = baseProj;
      map.maxExtent = maxExt;
      map.setCenter(center);
   }
}
```

Comment: The second link may work, but I won't know until I return to work on Monday. Thank you.

Comment: no worries take your time :)